# I want the value to be false when I go to a different route and return to the old route. Because the sidebar stays open

Tags: angular, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8fJ2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa0Py.png)

- How i can set value false when I return to this site? I cant figure it out.

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: a lot of details is missing in your question. Please add a wider code snippet, avoid using screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to forcefully close sidebar on leaving the view, consider using `onDestroy` hook, where you can set `this.isShow` to false.